# I can't see Tensor Shape in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to train the model in tensorflow and get the shape of some tensor.
But I can't see Tensor Shape even if I use shape function.
I can only see the following output.

What should I do to see the shape of Tensor?

Code:

```
# mat is <class 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Tensor'>
tf.print(mat.shape)
```

Output:

```
TensorShape([None, None])
```

Comment: Could you please provide minimal code for how you created mat? Is this a layer inside the model architecture or the complete model? What is the output if you use just print? did you try mat.get_shape() and tf.shape(mat)?

Answer (score 0):

Try `mat.get_shape()` or `tf.shape(mat)`or `print(mat)`

Comment: Thank you for your comment.
I'm going to try the above function later.